# � in base64 encoded emails

Tags: php, email, outlook, mime

I have a problem with Swedish language + MS Outlook.

It all works nice and dandy everywhere but MS Outlook. In MS Outlook Swedish characters show as �. Email contents is base64 encoded, uft-8 etc. What can be wrong?

**ADDENDUM:**

This is the message:

```
============================================================  
Header 
============================================================ 

*** NY Beställning *** 

Ni har fått ny beställning från: FirstAccount 

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
Beställnings-ID: FA12914-1  
Beställningsdetaljer: http://somelink
Beställningsdatum: 11/14/2011 11:16  
Önskat leveransdatum:   
Ordersedel: http://somlink 
Original: <http://somelink> 
Product: New stuff 
Product ID:   
Description:  
Qty: 11 
Job type: Release from stock

Kommenar:  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


_______________________________________________________________ 
Copyright (c) 2011 Someone
```

And this is the source:

```
Return-path: <test@example.com>
Envelope-to: admin@example.com
Delivery-date: Mon, 14 Nov 2011 11:17:00 +0000
Received: from somewhere ([123.456.789.012])
        by someone.co.uk with esmtp (Exim 4.69)
        (envelope-from <test@example.com>)
        id 1RPuX1-0006sU-HG
        for admin@example.com; Mon, 14 Nov 2011 11:16:58 +0000
Received: by someone.co.ul (Postfix, from userid 33)
        id B743C4EB7F; Mon, 14 Nov 2011 11:16:52 +0000 (UTC)
To: "Admin" <admin@example.com>
Subject: Ny beställning har kommit in från ace Beställnings-ID: FA12914-1
From: test@example.com
X-Mailer: Html Mime Mail Class
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;

   boundary="=_41bea315b9b2f2301a97632f8d6c3057"
Message-Id: <20111114111652.B743C4EB7F@li214-208.members.linode.com>
Date: Mon, 14 Nov 2011 11:16:52 +0000 (UTC)
X-Spam-Status: No, score=1.4
X-Spam-Score: 14
X-Spam-Bar: +
X-Ham-Report: Spam detection software, running on the system "somewhere", has
   identified this incoming email as possible spam.  The original message
   has been attached to this so you can view it (if it isn't spam) or label
   similar future email.  If you have any questions, see
   the administrator of that system for details.
X-Spam-Flag: NO


This is a MIME encoded message.

--=_41bea315b9b2f2301a97632f8d6c3057
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09

PT09IA0KYWNlIA0KPT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09

PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09IA0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIA0KKioqIE5ZIEJlc3TDpGxsbmluZyAq

KiogDQ........

--=_41bea315b9b2f2301a97632f8d6c3057--
```

Comment: Show a representative sample message; its MIME headers and a few bytes of content. I strongly suspect that your messages are flawed, but it could of course be a bug in Outlook as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pasted message source appears to have a spurious newline in the middle of the Content-Type: header.  It should be a single logical line; although perhaps you pasted it wrong (the Received: headers at least have not been pasted correctly).  Something similar appears to have happened in the base64 body part -- we see empty lines between the lines of data.

It looks like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;

boundary="=_41bea315b9b2f2301a97632f8d6c3057"
```

It should be:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
   boundary="=_41bea315b9b2f2301a97632f8d6c3057"
```

with at least one whitespace character before the "boundary" keyword; or even

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="=_41bea315b9b2f2301a97632f8d6c3057"
```

Additionally, you should RFC2047-encode the Subject line if it contains 8-bit data.

```
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Ny_best=C3=A4llning_har_kommit_in_fr=C3=A5n_ace_Best=C3=A4llnings-ID:_FA12914-1?=
```

After removing the newlines, the base64 data in the body part looks correct, i.e. the word "Beställning" shows correctly (although it should properly not be proper-cased; perhaps there is a Swedish.stackexchange.com for critique of your copy? :-)

The X-Mailer: header indicates that you are generating these messages with a piece of software; it probably has options to do these things right, but you are not using them.  This is a programming forum so you should probably show us your code, and tag the question with the appropriate programming language.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have updated the header to look exactly as it looks in the original message and there is a new line indeed.

Comment: I am using PHP but the problem is code is so f...d up that I am not even sure which part I should show. I inherited a large code base written by some people who had no clue. Now I fire fight it. Thanks I will check the header thing and let you know if it helped. 
As for subject... I tried encoding it but then it does not get decoded by Thunderbird... and actually subject is the only part that does display Swedish characters properly in the Outlook - without encoding.

Comment: Without any information about the actual code, not much we can do to help you fix it. I wrote the RFC2047 Subject header by hand, maybe I made a mistake, or forgot something. It's not important for your problem anyway.

Comment: Typical PHP code with mistakes in it would create an object called `$message` or `$header`, then modify it as a string instead of using its documented interface to add and modify headers, MIME parts, etc with no regard to what correct, working MIME needs to look like.